# How to lock a table in access 2013?

Tags: locking, edit, ms-access-2013

Trying to lock a table in Access 2013, so the data in the table and its structure are not editable, but are able to be read. How to do this? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds silly, but have you tried manually setting the file properties as "Read-only"?
To do this, close the database and right-click the file. Go to Properties, down to Attributes and check the box next to "Read-only"